data recovery in mint
I was originally using windows 10 when I had formatted my system twice to use ubuntu and now i have installed linux mint. Is there any chance I will be able to recover those old files?
I am currently trying my luck with testdisk and then I'll try photorec. Any suggestion is appreciated.

You can try, but if you're using SSD like most systems these days, most likely all data is instantly discarded at mkfs time... no recovery possible.

This question is similar to: Accidentally installed Linux Mint over Windows/Ubuntu. How do I recover data (SSD)?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.


Is there any chance I will be able to recover those old files?

yes, anything with a non-zero probability has a chance of happening, but I'll say that in your situation it almost certainly is impossible to recover significant ampounts of your data. The moment the Linux tooling for making file systems is called on a partition, it tells the device to wipe the data. And, if that device is an SSD, that's an instant operation which will literally just set all the bits to zero in an instant (at least from a perspective that your computer can see). Same is true for shingled-recording hard drives (you probably don't have one of these, unless you bought a hard drive specifically advertised as large-capacity backup storage/video recorder storage).
If it's not an SSD, but a "normal" hard drive, chances are better that some data survived. But two formattings and OS installations later? Seems pretty unlikely to me, unless you had filled your disk under windows pretty evenly (not something that windows usually does, unless you completely fill your disk), and only need to recover some examples, not large files.
